The Merchant's coin weighing
You're a merchant in the old medieval times, and a customer has come to you to buy something for 13 coins. You know him of course, like everyone in town, and you know he's a sketchy guy. Someone who would scam you sketchy. You stare him down as he pulls 12 coins from one bag, and one other coin from another bag. The flickering light from the oil candles makes it very difficult to see in the dim light as he places all 13 coins on the table, so you don't know which one is the coin he pulled out from the other bag.
Knowing him, you realise that the one separate coin he pulled out from another bag was a counterfeit (for all intents and purposes, you wouldn't know that the other coin is fake, but for this puzzle, assume it is a counterfeit). All the coins look the same, but you know the counterfeit coin has a different weight (you don't know if it's lighter or heavier). You have another coin in your pocket, the 14th coin, that you know is genuine.
You want to quickly prove that the customer is a scammer by finding the counterfeit coin. You have a scale balance with you and you want to find it in three weighings or less, to be efficient and quickly move on to your next customer.
The question is, is it possible for you, the merchant, to figure out the counterfeit coin in three weighings or less on a scale balance? Find a possible strategy to figure it out.

Without the flavour text (TL;DR):

You have 13 coins, where one coin is fake and the other 12 is real
You have another coin, the 14th coin, which you 100% know is real and genuine
You don't know which one is fake by looking at it
You know that the counterfeit/fake coin has a different weight, but you don't know if its lighter or heavier
You have a scale balance, and you need to find a strategy to find out the counterfeit coin in 3 weighings or less. You can only compare 2 different groups of coins, not some out-of-the-box weighing

The checkmark will go to the first person to find one possible way to find the counterfeit coin in three weighings or less. Generalisations or a full solution are welcome, but your reward will only be praise in the comments.

It seems like this puzzle is well-known. Did you come up with it independently?

This is a variation of the well-known 12-coin problem.  It works with 13 coins if you know for sure one of them is fake.  Though it won't always prove the fakeness of the coin you identify.

See here and, more generally, here

See this wikipedia entry about 13 coins with a reference coin
